# using Superscript on Preheader inside the AMPScript

Tags: marketing-cloud, email-template, ampscript

I use AMPScript on PreHeader and Subject for emails on Exact Target.
I want to add Superscript on one of them,but just display # as a usual symbol, it doesn't do Superscript on that.
I am trying to use this tag :  inside the AMPScript on preheader.

How can I handle it?

Thanks

Comment: What happens when you use the <sup> tags for superscript?  Nothing?

Answer (score 1):

The subject line and preheader text display based on the email client your subscriber is viewing with.

HTML tags will have no affect on the subject line and preheader, so using the superscript tag here would not do anything.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced same issue for preview text in SFMC. The text is superscripted in Subject line and pre-header. However, Preview text is a plain text and it catch only plain text available on all over the email content. It will not superscript for preview text. I used  tag for preheader. and that superscripted content put out of the anchor tag. Issue has resolved.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.